# Replacing pandas column value with values from another column

Tags: python, image, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe like so, lets say x:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1ohI.png)

And there is another dataframe with descriptions for the labelNames like so, lets say y:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BELwg.png)

Now, How do I replace the LabelNames in the x with the description in the y?
Know that LabelNames in x is not unique

Comment: Please edit the data into your question in a format that lets us try things without having to type it out again. Also include an example output of what you want to achieve. [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) might be what you want, but it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use index matching:

```
x = x.set_index('LabelName')
y = y.set_index('LabelName')
```

Then

```
x['Description'] = y.ClassDescription
```